# PHP Determine Monthly Day of Week

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I've seen lots of "Date" related questions here, however, I haven't been able to find one that calculates this:

I am trying to figure out the numerical value of a given date string.  For example:

```
 $date = "2010-09-01";
```

Given the date above, how might I be able to determine that this is the "1st" Wednesday of the month.

I know that: `date("l", $date);`  will tell me that it's a Wednesday, but how do I determine if it's the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, or 4th Wednesday of the Month?

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets you what you want:

```
$i = (int) (($day_of_month + 6) / 7);
```

where `$day_of_month` is from 1 to 31.

Comment: Thanks konforce.  That was it!

Answer (score 1):

You just need a little bit of maths.

If the day of the month is < 8, then it's the first Wednesday. Or Friday. Or Monday. Or Saturday. So if it's between 7 and 15, then it's the second whatever. And so on. @konforce has posted the actual formula.